# How to express select with max() and ifnull() in peewee

Tags: sqlite, peewee

I have a SQLite-Select statement like this to get the next *available* number:
`SELECT IFNULL(MAX(current_nr)+1, 1) FROM rm_evaluation;`

I already have a corresponding model in python peewee:
`class RmRiskEvaluation(BaseModel):
...
    current_nr = IntegerField(unique=True)
    class Meta:
        table_name = 'rm_evaluation'`

But how can I express the SQL-statement from above.
=> Get the last number, add 1 to it and return the whole thang; if there is no last number at all, calculate with 1 beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you weren't so lazy and had spent even a couple minutes reading the docs or searching, you would have found your answer.

```
fn.IFNULL(fn.MAX(RmRiskEvaluation.current_nr) + 1, 1)
```

Comment: Tried this -> https://ibb.co/1z1bg7m
Obiously not hard enough.
Please take my apologies.